# Arctic char available in North-America

Tags: fish

I am from Scandinavia, and I am currently living in North-America. I am having problems finding this species of fish, usually referred to as [Arctic Char](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_char). It is closely related to salmon and trout. Is it farmed in North-America at all?

According to the article, a subspecies is known as blueback trout but was extirpated. Does this species survive in the waters here at all? Can it be bought fresh?

I think this species of fish if referred to under a different name in the US.

Comment: Where in North America?  I live in the suburbs of Philadelphia, PA.  I see Arctic Char in seafood markets pretty consistently.

Answer (score 2):

My first reaction was to be surprised by your question as Arctic Char is fairly common in Alaska, I didn't realize that it is hard to find in the lower 48.

[image]

It's closely related to salmon, so salmon would be a reasonable substitute for most applications.

This article tells more of its range in the wild (far north) [Arctic Char](http://ww2.odu.edu/sci/cqfe/Research/Arctic/Arctic%20char/Arctic_Char.htm). It is farmed in the US [Farmed Arctic Char](http://ww2.odu.edu/sci/cqfe/Research/Arctic/Arctic%20char/Arctic_Char.htm) but not in huge numbers. I'm not aware of it being known by any other name.

Comment: when I lived in the Midwest, it was considered kind of exotic, but was still pretty widely available (any grocery store with a decent seafood counter had it)

Comment: I´m not sure salmon would be the correct replacement. I feel the taste of salmon is "heavier" and richer, more intense. I would think the correct replacement to be some species of trout, since char and trout belong to the same Salmonidae subfamily, Salvelinus.

Answer (score 2):

First, it doesn't go by another name in Canada (in English, anyway, it has [an Inuktitut name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_char).) I see it regularly on menus and in grocery stores in small Ontario cities. Not a hard fish to find at all. There are also [fishing expeditions](http://www.arcticchar.ca/) to catch your own. The Canadian [Department of Fisheries and Oceans](http://www.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/fm-gp/sustainable-durable/fisheries-peches/char-omble-eng.htm) says:

> Arctic char are a highly priced delicacy, marketed mainly fresh and frozen as whole-dressed fish and steaks. A small quantity is also processed into value–added products including smoked char and jerky.
>
> Commercial landings were 57 tonnes in 2012 , 52 tonnes in 2011, 29.4 tonnes in 2010 and 31.8 in 2009.

It is also [farmed](http://www.aquaculture.ca/files/species-arctic-charr.php) in Canada and the farmed product is considered sustainable.

You didn't say what city you're in, but if it's large enough to have a fishmonger I suspect a phone call will be all it takes to find out if some is in stock. If not, call a few grocery stores.

Answer (score 0):

I caught one yesterday at lake Dillon in silverthorne colorado but they are very rare in the lower 48 and you can only find them here and in one lake in Maine so if you want Arctic char go to Alaska or Greenland or Europe

Answer (score 0):

In N America you would need go some place like.Humphries Market. Small market that does handle imported fish, elk, buffalo & such. Then order them from them frozen.

Answer (score 0):

I live in Farmington, Michigan. Last summer, 2017, we found Arctic char regularly at our local grocery; but this summer, we can't find it anywhere.